Is there a good algorithm for this delay-based graph problem?
Imagine an undirected graph of nodes connected by edges.  Every node has a safety attribute: the node is either SAFE or TOXIC.  There are no isolated "islands" of nodes in the graph that are not connected to the rest of the graph.
A traversal of the graph is needed, that visits every node, including the TOXIC ones, but delays the TOXIC visits for as long as possible.  Formally put, a correct traversal is one that contains the fewest possible visits to TOXIC nodes before any given subset of SAFE nodes has been visited.
Non-goal: this is not the Seven Bridges of Königsberg game.  There is no requirement to visit every node exactly once, nor to traverse every edge exactly once.  Assume that once any node has been previously visited, it is possible to teleport from the current position to the previously-visited node at zero cost.
Is there any reasonably-efficient algorithm to find a correct traversal of this graph?
